# Cannot plot predicted time series values using matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, statsmodels

I am trying to plot my actual time series values and predicted values but it gives me this error:

> **ValueError**: view limit minimum -36816.95989583333 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

I am using `statsmodels` to fit an arima model to the data.

This is a sample of my data:

```
datetime             value
2017-01-01 00:00:00  10.18
2017-01-01 00:15:00  10.2
2017-01-01 00:30:00  10.32
2017-01-01 00:45:00  10.16
2017-01-01 01:00:00  9.93
2017-01-01 01:15:00  9.77
2017-01-01 01:30:00  9.47
2017-01-01 01:45:00  9.08
```

This is my code:

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    subset,
    order=(1, 1, 1),
    seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12),
    enforce_stationarity=False,
    enforce_invertibility=False
)

results = mod.fit()
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=500)
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int(alpha = 0.05)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(subset,color = "blue")
ax.plot(pred_uc.predicted_mean, color="black", alpha=0.5, label='SARIMAX')
plt.show()
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I removed some unnecessary lines of code .. just edited now.

Comment: Also give a sample of the data you are working on

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan done

Comment: How do you define `subset`?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('interpolated-detailed.csv')
df.set_index('datetime')
subset = df[(df['datetime'] > "2017-01-04") & (df['datetime'] < "2017-01-05")]
subset = subset.iloc[:, 0:2]
` @Georgy

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example but `sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX` doesn't like my `subset` for some reason: `ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).` Converting with `pd.to_datetime` didn't help

Comment: did you try `subset.set_index(subset["datetime"])` before calling `sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX`

Comment: sorry meant `subset = subset.set_index("datetime")` @Georgy

Comment: Ok, now it works, and, actually, I don't get any errors. Did you try printing `subset` and `pred_uc.predicted_mean` before plotting to check if the format of datetimes is the same?

Comment: @Georgy The error has gone now , I don't remember how , but now I have another problem that The ARIMA model is not well fitted with the data.

Comment: Then I suggest creating another post. And this one should be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: I just ran into this issue. My problem was that the datetime column actually contained strings and not dates. So I had to convert using `pd.to_datetime`. My next guess was to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21108350/163668

Answer (score 1):

It should have been an issue on how you provide the data.

The `datetime` values must be the index of the `values` in your data `subset` variable, and thus, the following works.

I've imported the data as follows right before the code you provided:

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> import numpy as np
>
> import pandas as pd
>
> import statsmodels.api as sm
>
> subset = pd.Series(
>
> [
>
>     10.18, 10.2 , 10.32,
>     10.16, 9.93, 9.77,
>     9.47, 9.08
>
> ]
>
> , index=pd.date_range(
>
>     start='2017-01-01T00:00:00.000',
>
>     end='2017-01-01T01:45:00.000',
>
>     freq='15T'
>
> )  )
> ```

And I got, I believe, your desired plot (it's cut):

[image: plot_result_cut].

I used these versions of the libraries, in Python 3:

matplotlib.**version**
'3.1.2'

numpy.**version**
'1.17.4'

pandas.**version**
'0.25.3'

statsmodels.**version**
'0.12.0'